# Json upload does not work on Samsung devices

Tags: android, json

I use the following code to upload a Json object to the server.

```
public static User registerUser(User user) {

    HttpClient client = null;

    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
            "http://www.someurl.com/update/");
    post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    JSONObject inputJson = new JSONObject();
    try {
        inputJson.put("name", user.getName());
        inputJson.put("username", user.getUsername());
        inputJson.put("email", user.getEmail());
        inputJson.put("gender", user.getGender());
        inputJson.put("location", user.getLocation());
        inputJson.put("password", user.getPassword());
        inputJson.put("deviceId", user.getDeviceId());
        inputJson.put("contactNumber", user.getContactNumber());
        inputJson.put("dateOfBirth", user.getDateOfBirth().getTime());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String input = inputJson.toString();

    try {
        post.setEntity(new StringEntity(input));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // handle exception
        Log.d("registrattion", e1.getMessage());
    }

    HttpResponse response = null;

    try {
        response = client.execute(post);
        Log.d("upload", "write");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d("res", response.getStatusLine().toString());

    return user;
}
```

The server does not detect any Json call. The code works on HTC and Lenovo devices. It also works on Huawei devices which are the most commonly used devices in my country. It does not work on Samsung devices. What might be the problem?

Comment: and you don't have any errors in logcat, right?

Comment: You can't get any unless you root the device.

Comment: if you are looking it in IDE via ADB, you don't need rooted device

Comment: For some reasons I am not able to install apps to my Samsung devices using ADB or read logcat from them.

Comment: I am experiencing same problem, is there any solution update?
To be clear, valid JSON is going out as verified in LogCat and receipt from other Android and iOS clients. However, one of our Samsung device clients is sending some sort of encryption of the JSON to the server.
The User-Agent for the encrypted/obfuscated data is: `Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; SAMSUNG-SM-G900A Build/KOT49H)`